# Prove the inequality: $\frac{a}{c+a-b}+\frac{b}{a+b-c}+\frac{c}{b+c-a}\ge{3}$

Tags: inequality

Prove the inequality:

$\frac{a}{c+a-b}+\frac{b}{a+b-c}+\frac{c}{b+c-a}\ge{3}$

Where $a,b,c$ are sides of a triangle.

It is clear that $c+a-b$ is positive but how to use it?

Comment: How about using AM $\geq HM$ on the positive reals $(a+b-c)^{-1}, (b+c-a)^{-1},(c+a-b)^{-1}$ ? Will it work ?

Comment: http://www.imomath.com/index.php?options=602&lmm=0

Comment: Thats more than enough

Comment: [Same question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/374373)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$a+b-c=x>0$$
$$c+a-b=y>0$$
$$b+c-a=z>0$$
The original inequality becomes
$$\frac{x+y}{2y}+\frac{x+z}{2x}+\frac{y+z}{2z}\geq 3$$
$$\frac{x}{2y}+\frac{z}{2x}+\frac{y}{2z}\geq \frac{3}{2}$$ which is trivial by AM-GM inequality

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

use this substitution
$$a=y+z,\quad b=x+z,\quad c=x+y$$