# Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be the three sides of a triangle. Show that $\frac{a}{b+c-a}+\frac{b}{c+a-b} + \frac{c}{a+b-c}\geqslant3$.

Tags: inequality, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, triangles, geometric-inequalities

> Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be the three sides of a triangle.
> Show that $$\frac{a}{b+c-a}+\frac{b}{c+a-b} + \frac{c}{a+b-c}\geqslant3\,.$$

A full expanding results in:
$$\sum_{cyc}a(a+b-c)(a+c-b)\geq3\prod_{cyc}(a+b-c),$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^3-ab^2-ac^2+2abc)\geq\sum_{cyc}(-3a^3+3a^2b+3a^2c-2abc),$$ but it becomes very ugly.

Comment: First thing you should try is [Ravi substitution](https://mblog1024.wordpress.com/2011/02/14/ravi-substitution-explained/).

Comment: See also [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1039406). This question is different, but most likely it can be solved analoguously.

Comment: @barto Can you please kindly help? I've tried using Ravi substitution. But I'm not able to reach the final output.

Comment: @barto Please the duplicate you posted. Its clearly different. Please dont flag it.

Comment: The example given by @barto is useful, as using rearrangement inequality, one can show $$\frac{a}{b+c-a}+\frac{b}{c+a-b} + \frac{c}{a+b-c} \ge \frac{a}{c+a-b}+\frac{b}{a+b-c}+\frac{c}{b+c-a}$$

Comment: Assume the denominators are positive numbers $x,y,z$ respectively. Can you express $a,b,c$ in terms of $x,y,z$? Then AM-GM will be your friend.

Comment: Also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/374373/prove-the-inequality-fracaca-b-fracbab-c-fraccbc-a-ge3 and here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1039406/prove-the-inequality-fracaca-b-fracbab-c-fraccbc-a-ge3 (from the Related list)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$a, b, c$ are sides of a triangle iff there exists positive reals $x, y, z$ s.t. $a=x+y, b=y+z, c = z+x$.  In terms of these variables, the inequality is
$$\sum_{cyc} \frac{a}{b+c-a} = \sum_{cyc} \frac{x+y}{2z} \ge 3$$

Now the last is easy to show with AM-GM of all $6$ terms.
$$\sum_{cyc} \frac{x+y}{2z} = \frac12\left(\frac{x}z+\frac{y}z+\frac{y}x+\frac{z}x+\frac{z}y+\frac{x}y \right) \ge \frac12\left(6\sqrt[6]{\frac{x}z\cdot\frac{y}z\cdot\frac{y}x\cdot\frac{z}x\cdot\frac{z}y\cdot\frac{x}y} \right) = 3$$

Comment: I'm not getting anything. How can you say that a,b,c is related to x,y,z? What's the intuition?

Comment: $x = \frac{c + a - b}{2}$, $y = \frac{a + b - c}{2}$, $z = \frac{b + c - a}{2}$

Comment: Did you see the Ravi link?  Draw an incircle - the circle that touches all three sides of the triangle.  This cuts the $a,b,c$ sides into $x+y,y+z,z+x$ respectively.

Comment: @NS We know by triangle inequality, $a+b-c, b+c-a, c+a-b$ must be non-negative / positive if you have non-degenerate triangles.  $x, y, z$ are simply non-negative / positive variables which capture the triangle inequality.

Comment: Wow thanks for such clear understanding!! Really a great forum. Thanks a lot @Macavity

Comment: @ALL Can someone please help to use MathJax so that I can write questions properly? Any mathjax easy to use online editor?

Comment: @Macavity Can you please explain the AM GM part? What's the intuition?

Comment: @NS for MathJax, see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020. For an online editor, see http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php

Comment: @NS added that in the post...

Comment: @Macavity frac12\left(6\sqrt[6]{1} \right Can you please explain this part? I apologise if I'm asking very silly questions. Can you please explain how you coming to that result?

Comment: How come my Tex is not being rendered in the comments? What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @NS AM-GM of six terms does exactly that.  Check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means#The_inequality

Comment: @NS you need to enclose the tex within curly braces "{...}"  did you check the link barto shared?

Comment: @Macavity Oh yes.. But again a question how come each of the term is being considered to have a minimum value of 1?

Comment: @NS you need to brush up on AM-GM, the link is already shared .  I have clarified in the post.

Answer (score 4):

Set $b+c-a=x, a+c-b=y$ and $a+b-c=z$
Due to triangular inequality, $x,y,z$ are positive. Hence we can apply the AM-GM inequality.
We have $x+y=b+c-a+a+c-b=2c \implies c = \frac{x+y}{2}$
Similarly $a = \frac{y+z}{2}$ and $b = \frac{z+x}{2}$
Now we have,
$$\frac{a}{b+c-a}+\frac{b}{a+c-b}+\frac{c}{a+b-c}=\frac{y+z}{2x}+\frac{z+x}{2y}+\frac{x+y}{2z}$$
$$\Leftrightarrow 2\left ( \frac{a}{b+c-a}+\frac{b}{a+c-b}+\frac{c}{a+b-c} \right )=\left ( \frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{x} \right )+\left ( \frac{y}{z}+\frac{z}{y} \right )+\left ( \frac{z}{x}+\frac{x}{z} \right )\geq 6$$
Hence $\ $ $\frac{a}{b+c-a}+\frac{b}{a+c-b}+\frac{c}{a+b-c}\geq 3$

Comment: so this has nothing to do with triangles?

Comment: Of course it has to do something with triangles. The positivity of x,y,z are due to triangular inequality.

Answer (score 3):

By C-S $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a}{b+c-a}=\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a^2}{ab+ac-a^2}\geq\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(2ab-a^2)}\geq3$, where the last inequality it's just
$$\sum\limits_{cyc}(a-b)^2\geq0.$$
Done!

Answer (score 2):

$\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a}{b+c-a}-3=\sum\limits_{cyc}\left(\frac{a}{b+c-a}-1\right)=\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a-b-(c-a)}{b+c-a}=$
$=\sum\limits_{cyc}(a-b)\left(\frac{1}{b+c-a}-\frac{1}{a+c-b}\right)=\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{2(a-b)^2}{(b+c-a)(a+c-b)}\geq0$

Answer (score 2):

Since $(a,b,c)$ and $\left(\frac{1}{b+c-a},\frac{1}{a+c-b},\frac{1}{a+b-c}\right)$ are the same ordered, by Chebyshov and C-S we obtain:
$\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a}{b+c-a}\geq\frac{1}{3}(a+b+c)\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{1}{b+c-a}=\frac{1}{3}\sum\limits_{cyc}(b+c-a)\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{1}{b+c-a}\geq\frac{1}{3}\cdot9=3$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $S>0$. Then for $x\in(0,S/2)$, the function $f(x)=\frac{x}{S-2x}$ is convex. Thus, by Jensen's inequality and with $S=a+b+c$, we have
$$
\frac{1}{3}f(a)+\frac{1}{3}f(b)+\frac{1}{3}f(c)\geq f\left(\frac{1}{3}(a+b+c)\right)=\frac{S/3}{S-2S/3}=1.
$$
This is equivalent to $f(a)+f(b)+f(c)\geq 3$, which is your inequality.

Answer (score 0):

Since $a,b,c$ are sides of a triangle, we can set $a = x+y$, $b = x+z$, $c = y+z$.

Plugging that in gives

\begin{align}
\frac{a}{b+c-a}+\frac{b}{a+c-b}+\frac{c}{a+b-c} &= \frac{x+y}{2z} + \frac{x+z}{2y} + \frac{y+z}{2x} \\
&= \frac{xy(x+y) + xz(x+z) + yz(y+z)}{2xyz}\\
&= \frac{x^2y+ xy^2 + x^2z + xz^2 + y^2z + yz^2}{2xyz}\\
&\ge \frac{3}{xyz}\sqrt[6]{x^6y^6z^6}\\
&= 3
\end{align}